# JSF Datatable "elegant" way to edit the content of a row

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

**EDIT1**:
As suggested by Valentin Jacquemin i implemented it with one `List<Entry<String,String>>`
however, when i now change a value, tomcat throws an error:
error message:

```
    SEVERE: /bvDesktop_RuleOverviewAddActionNode.xhtml at line 111 and column 115 value="#{paramListKVs.value}": Property 'value' not writable on type java.lang.Object
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /bvDesktop_RuleOverviewAddActionNode.xhtml at line 111 and column 115 value="#{paramListKVs.value}": Property 'value' not writable on type java.lang.Object
```

And the corresponding line in my xhtml:

```html
<p:dataTable id="paramListKV" var="paramListKVs" value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.paramListKV}" editable="true" editMode="cell">
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">List Key</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{paramListKVs.key}"/>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:cellEditor id="paramListKVsEditTest"> 
             <f:facet name="header">List Value</f:facet>
             <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{paramListKVs.value}"/></f:facet>
             --><f:facet name="input"><p:inputText value="#{paramListKVs.value}" style="width:96%" /></f:facet><--
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

marked by --> and <--.
I don't know what java tries to write the code to. I'm not even sure if `value="#{paramListKVs.value}"`is correct. Any ideas?

---

I have a particular problem i was able to solve, but i feel like my solution is more like a dirty way. I hope that there is a more elegant way to do this, but i wasn't able to find one (searched so). So here is my problem:

I'm currently creating a rule-based framework for automated processing of some files and I want to give our editors the possibility to create those rules in a nice and easy web interface. 
I already have the required websites,datamodel and so on. However one particular problem is, that an Action-Rule can have a `Set of Properties Key-Value` wise. I choose a `TreeMap`. Now i want to be able to `add`, `delete` and `edit` the cells in the representing datatable.

Java:
createActioNode:

```
@ManagedBean
public class RuleTreeBeanAddActionNode {
...
        private TreeMap<String,String> actionParamMap = new TreeMap<String,String>(); 

        private String paramKeyToAdd = "";

        private String paramValueToAdd = "";

        private int paramKeyIndex;

        private String valueToChange;

        private String keyForInfo;

        private UIComponent datatable;

        public void addKeyValueToMap() {

            if((paramKeyToAdd != null || !paramKeyToAdd.equals("")) && (paramValueToAdd != null) || !paramValueToAdd.equals("")) {
            unusedActionParamKeys.remove(paramKeyToAdd);
            usedActionParamKeys.add(paramKeyToAdd);

            actionParamsAsListKeys.add(paramKeyToAdd);
            actionParamsAsListValues.add(paramValueToAdd);

            actionParamMap.put(paramKeyToAdd, paramValueToAdd);
            actionParamMapEntries = new ArrayList<Entry<Integer, String>>((Collection<? extends Entry<Integer, String>>) actionParamMap.entrySet());
            userSession.setAttribute("actionParamMap", actionParamMap);
            userSession.setAttribute("unusedActionParamKeys", unusedActionParamKeys);
            userSession.setAttribute("usedActionParamKeys", usedActionParamKeys);
            userSession.setAttribute("tempSelectorWorkOn", "");
            userSession.setAttribute("tempRuleId", "");

            userSession.setAttribute("actionParamsAsListKeys", actionParamsAsListKeys);
            userSession.setAttribute("actionParamsAsListValues", actionParamsAsListValues);

            paramKeyToAdd = "";
            paramValueToAdd = "";
           }
        }

        public void setValueToChange(String valueToChange) {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)datatable;
            String id = String.valueOf(paramKeyIndex);
            Entry<String, String> temp = (Entry<String, String>)dt.getRowData();
            actionParamMap.put((String) temp.getKey(), valueToChange);
    }

        //getter and setter
```

createActionNode.xhtml

```html
<tr>
    <td>Action Parameter </td>
    <td>
        <p:dataTable binding="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.datatable}" 
                     rowKey="test" 
                     rowIndexVar="paramKeyIndex" 
                     id="paramKeysValues" 
                     var="params" 
                     value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.actionParamMapEntries}" 
                     editable="true" 
                     editMode="cell">
            <p:column id="keys">
                <f:facet name="header">Param Key</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{params.key}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column id="values">
                <f:facet name="header">Param Value</f:facet>
                <p:cellEditor id="paramValueEdit">  
                   <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{params.value}"/></f:facet>  
                   <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="evinput" value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.valueToChange}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>  
                </p:cellEditor>  
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr><td><br/></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td>Param To Value</td>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="paramKeys" value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.paramKeyToAdd}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.unusedActionParamKeys}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p:inputText id="paramValue" value="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.paramValueToAdd}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <p:commandButton id="addParam" value="+" action="#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.addKeyValueToMap}" update="paramKeysValues,paramKeys,paramValue"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I understood that i need to return not the map but the entry set, so that the datatable can iterarte through it. So when i edit a record in the cell, the function
`#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.valueToChange}` is called on a change. However to retrieve the actual record and thus the key and value to change in the map, i have to go over the `UIComponent` of `Datatable`, retrieve the edited record,save the map and rebuild the entry set.
 
**So my actual question is**, is this the recommended way? Did i oversee something that would make my world much easier? Has someone else implemented something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for [UIData](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html), which any datatable is child of:

> UIData is a UIComponent that supports data binding to a collection of
>   data objects represented by a DataModel instance, which is the current
>   value of this component itself (typically established via a
>   ValueExpression). During iterative processing over the rows of data in
>   the data model, the object for the current row is exposed as a request
>   attribute under the key specified by the var property.

Thus as you said you need an iterable object so that the datatable can loop through it and expose each element when building the table.

On the other hand, you're not leveraging on the binding feature completely here. Simply let the component doing its job and set `value=#{ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.actionParams}`, `actionParams` being a `List` or any other [supported type](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getValue%28%29). Once done, your datatable's model will reference your `ruleTreeBeanAddActionNode.actionParams` elements. You don't need any further mechanism to do the sync.

See also:

- [Using Data-Bound Table Components](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnarz/index.html)

UPDATE

I guess you tried to use the [AbstractMap.SimpleEntry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) as entries of your list. This class is not JavaBean compatible though as the `setValue` is not of type `void`. Create your own object holding the state of your row so that you've a JavaBean compatible object and EL will be able to resolve the read/write methods correctly:

```
public class Entry{
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public Entry(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {return key;}
    public String getValue() {return value;}
    public void setKey(String key) {this.key = key;}
    public void setValue(String value) {this.value = value;}
}
```

Then in your backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class RuleTreeBeanAddActionNode {
    private List<Entry> entries;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        entries.add(new Entry("foo", "bar"));
    }

    public List<Entry> getEntries() { return entries; }
}
```

Comment: Mhh. The Problem is that i do not want to work with a list. I would like to have the Map in the site. It's a bit hard to have a Key-Value-List and work on that.

Comment: Ok i think i implemented it correctly now. Two Lists, one for the Key one for the Value, but i still need to change the values myself. 
I used the onmouseout with a this.form.submit() and then i have both values in my backing bean and now i can change the value in the list. 
But still i think this is not the best way to do it. 
Somehow i can't get it to work so that the changes to the list are done automatically. :(

Comment: I still advise you to get rid of your map. Simply declare a new object if needed (i.e. Entry with a key and value properties) and provide in your backing bean a list of them. Then no need to keep the sync logic yourself.

Comment: I did add the list implementation additionally to the map. I wanted to test the implementation before i throw the map away. 
Next step is to implement a K-V List. 
I'm thinking about SimpleEntry. Let's see if i get that to work. 

But just for me:
Technically if i use just one list with K-V as value, the list should be updated when i edit one element of it, e.g. Key or Value, right?

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't work. See my edit from the original post :(

Comment: update your code listing to include the `paramListKV` getter. The error tells you the datatable loops on a list of `Object` and not list of `Entry`

Comment: Sorry Valentin, i don't quite understand. I have the getter and setter for paramListKV:
`public ArrayList<Entry<String, String>> getParamListKV() {
  return paramListKV;
 }

 
public void setParamListKV(ArrayList<Entry<String, String>> paramListKV) {
  this.paramListKV = paramListKV;
 }`

Am i missing something?

Comment: Where and how is `paramListKV` initiated?

Comment: In my Bean-Constructor:
`paramListKV =  (ArrayList<MyEntry>) userSession.getAttribute("paramListKV");
  if(paramListKV == null) {
  paramListKV = new ArrayList<MyEntry>(); 
  paramListKV.add(new MyEntry("test", "view"));
userSession.setAttribute("paramListKV", paramListKV);
 }` 
I also tried to work with my own Entry-Implementation, however now java throws the following error:
`Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /...value="#{paramListKVs.value}": Property 'value' not writable on type java.lang.String`
my guess is that it tries to write to the property directly not using the setter?

Comment: Oh man. I thank you so so much Valentin. This was the problem. How did you know it was not JavaBean compatible? Do you have an info site on that or some kind of specs? Now it works like a charm ... How can i give you credit for this(I'm new to s.o.) Thanks again. You rock! PS: why do i need to init the List in a `@PostConstruct` ? Or is it just not best practice to do this in the constructor of the bean? It should not be initialized more than once for each rule i create.

Comment: You're welcome Chris. Welcome on SO as well! Main rules of thumb regarding JavaBean: public getter/setter methods with according return type for the getter and void for the setter, empty constructor (eventhough not mandatory as you see in my answer). Regarding the PostConstruct, it's mainly a habit of mine. In the constructor you don't have the dependencies wired. I usually initialize what I'd do normally in the custructor inside the PostConstruct in JSF BackingBean.